# I accidentally activated this history search feature in powershell core. What is it called?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I have a rather unusual request - I accidentally activated this feature with my laptop keyboard:

[image]

**It shows all previous commands that match my command prompt. It is very useful, but it appears to be active for this one shell, and it was gone after I closed the terminal.**

What is this feature called, and how do I activate it for all terminal windows all the time?

I am using windows terminal and powershell core 7.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is intellisense autocompletion. I think you may need to hit F2 to enable it or use it.

https://www.poppastring.com/blog/powershell-intellisense-completion

Comment: The module for this is PSReadLine.  Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/